# Sweden UT Card holder can have non-Sweden country as point of entry

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, sweden, residency

I have a Sweden UT card (Resident Permit), and I am a non-EU citizen. Right now, I am in India. I have not used my Sweden UT card before. Is it possible for me to enter any other Schengen country (not Sweden) using my UT card? or the first point of entry using UT card needs to be Sweden?

Comment: Nah, no problems. You can enter Schengen from any country with your Swedish residence permit. Make sure your passport will be stamped - you may need this for immigration purposes later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter any Schengen country, but could be asked to Show a ticket to Sweden. You will not be checked when travelling from another Schengen country to Sweden by air